# error : variable c might not have been initialized

Tags: java

Below is a simple program, but I am not sure why an error is displayed when compiling:

```
class TwoControl {
public statis void main (String args[])  {
     int num,A,C;
     int B=5;
     num = 1;
     A=5;
     if(num<A)
     C=A+B;
     System.out.print("C Value " + C);
  }
}
```

There might be different ways to make this program run, but not sure why it is not working for the above coding form.

When I try to compile it, I get the error

```
Error : Variable C might not have been initialized System.out.print("C Value " + C);
```

Is it when the compiler compile the code, it will not verify the control statements?

In the above example the value `C` is initialized or defined if the condition is true, then is the compiler throwing error for the negative scenario?

Comment: What happens when `A >= num`?

Comment: In addition to below answers please follow java naming convention and also `statics` is incorrect its `static`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable `C` is only initialized within the condition:

```
if(num<A)
    C=A+B;
```

So if the condition is `false`, C is never initialized.

Either have an else clause or initialize it with a default value, i.e.:

```
int num,A,C = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

In case num >= A (reverse meaning of your condition), C will remain uninitialized.

You can fix it by defining C with a default value, for example `int C = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Ori said, if you make `C` as a class level variable, then the compiler will default it with 0, but as it is a method local, you need to initialize it:

```
class TwoControl {
    static int C;
public statis void main (String args[])  {
.....
```

This compiles perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise C when you declare.it

```
Int num,A,C = 0;
```

or put an else on the if before the assignment

```
    if(num<A)
    C=A+B;
    else
    C = 0;
    System.out.print("C Value " + C);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In your snippet of code, the variable C is inializated just if the condition num>A is true, the java compiler is not able to understand at compile time if num>A. Then the compiler is giving you the advice that C can't be used because it is not inializated ma it is just declared. You can solve it initializing C in this way:

```
int num,A,C=0;
```